# Neo4j cypher query to collect all the intermediate nodes along with the target nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to build a query to get all the people who lived in the same city as person `p`, and I also want to get all the city names where person `p` lived.

But this query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVED_IN]->(c:City)<-[:LIVED_IN]-(p1:Person)
WERE p.id = 0
RETURN p1, collect (DISTINCT c.name) AS cities
```

only returns the city names that each `p1` person also lived in.

Suppose person `p` lived in 2 cities and person `p1` lived in only one of them. I would only get one city in the result. I am looking to get all the results of the distinct cities in a variable, along with the list of `p1` persons.

If I use UNWIND operation to iterate through the cities and collect all the distinct city names, I am losing the variable `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of the names of all cities that `p` lived in, and a list of all other people who lived in any of those cities:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVED_IN]->(c:City)
WHERE p.id=0
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:LIVED_IN]-(p1:Person)
WHERE p1 <> p
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT c.name) as cities, COLLECT(DISTINCT p1) AS otherPeople
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the cities as a global variable because there are subsequent MATCH clauses after this which don't require it but I might need it in the last where clause.

Comment: Since we have made otherPeople as List<node>, I can't perform another MATCH operation with the nodes in the list directly without using UNWIND. If I use UNWIND, I might lose the cities within the UNWIND operation

Comment: cybersam might know another method, but when I want to preserve pairs, I use a list, e.g `WITH [c.name, p1] as myCityPersonPair` then you can `MATCH (c2 {name: myCityPersonPair[0]})`

Comment: @lazycoder All variables defined _within a single Cypher statement_ remain in scope (in the statement) until there is a [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) clause. A `WITH` clause must specify a variable (or the `*` wildcard) to pass it on to the remainder of the statement. There are no "global" variables that retain values _across different statements_, but you can create special nodes to store such values (but this pollutes your data model).

Comment: @lazycoder You do not "lose" variables after an `UNWIND`, but that can happen after a `WITH` (see my previous comment). Also, you don't have to use `UNWIND` to consume a list; for example: `MATCH (c) WHERE c IN cities`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here comes from this part of MATCH clause , `<-[:LIVED_IN]-(p1:Person)` , we generally use 'MATCH' clause to set a fixed structure/pattern in order to query our graph using it and start matching until find the structure what matches "exactly" what we have in 'MATCH' clause if exists.

in this case the MATCH clause is specified to be
`MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVED_IN]->(c:City)<-[:LIVED_IN]-(p1:Person)`
which means go find a pattern that exactly matches " a person node 'p' connected to a city node 'c' using "LIVED_IN" relation/edge and also this city **must** have at least another person node 'p1' living in it rather than the first person node 'p' ",
this cause that every "city" that only lived in by the person 'p' will not included as this doesn't matches the specified pattern we set.

in graph theory words ,

the given pattern will find only cities of at least 2 in Degree value of specific "LIVED_IN" relation one of them is our start person node "p" and any other node(s) and this make problem as we need "to get all the city names where person p lived" which some of these city nodes 'c' may have only 1 in Degree value ( only person p makes "LIVED_IN" relation with it ).

since our query target is to

- want to get all the city names where person p lived.
- get all the people who lived in the same city as person p ( if exist a common city node with LIVED_IN relation / edge ).

so we need to make our MATCH pattern less tight , somehow we need to have "optional" side of this pattern which is `<-[:LIVED_IN]-(p1:Person)`.

we may make use of "OPTIONAL MATCH" clause of cypher.

so the code will be like this ,

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVED_IN]->(c:City)
WHERE p.id = 0
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:LIVED_IN]-(other:Person)
WHERE other <> p
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT other.name) AS people , COLLECT(DISTINCT c.name) as cities
```